# How does Oracle calculate the running total just by using order by clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I'm very confused in trying to understand how SQL calculates the running total with just using "order by" clause and nothing else. There is no counter or increment happening in the query. Can anyone help me understand how detail it works at the data level?

My query to calculate the running total:

```
select ename, sal, sum(sal) over (order by sal) from emp;
```

How can the order by clause keep a track of the previous row and add values on top of it?

Comment: because this is a specific syntax of [analytic functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174). Another great page from [Tim Hall](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions) as well as a great series of videos from [Connor McDonald](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJMaoEWvHwFIUwMrF4HLnRksF0H8DHGtt)

Comment: But how does it keeps track of the previous row and adds the values on top  of it when the primary use of ORDER BY is just to sort values.

Comment: The counter/increment is internal to the `over()` mechanism, it doesn't need to be visible in the query itself. How Oracle implements that internally shouldn't really matter.

Comment: answer would be - I do not now, this is internal implementation of the Oracle DB. Unless anyone else could shed some light on that, you might want to investigate that yourself, for example same/similar concepts are implemented in PostgreSQL with source code available

Comment: i find no element in the above which could drive the cumulative addition. All we got is  a sum function and an over followed by an order by clause. At the first sight, this query looks like it gives the sum of all the salaries sorted based on the salary.

Comment: Another way of looking at it is that the SQL engine is treating `sum()` as an analytic rather than an aggregate function here, due to the presence of the `over()` windowing clause (and the lack of a `group by`). If you write your own aggregate function in PL/SQL you will find that it also works as an analytic function when called in this way, without any code changes.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is a *descriptive* language, not a *procedural* language.  That means that a query describes the result set being produced.  It does not specify the specific step-by-step methods for implementing them.

The compiler and optimizer turn a query into executable code -- typically a directed, acyclic graph of operations.  You can see this by investigating the explain plans for queries.

The simple answer to your question is that the designers of SQL have chosen the syntax you mention as the syntax for a conditional sum.  Oracle has implemented this syntax.  How this gets implemented is determined by the compiler and optimizer.

The more complex answer is that Oracle has multiple algorithms for doing the calculation.  For instance, sometimes the cumulative sum can take advantage of an index.  Sometimes it cannot.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate you're eager to understand the functionality. First of all you need to understand basic concepts of aggregate function and analytic function. Below example may give you fair idea. I have taken employees table,

[image]

If you see analytic function, **row_number** -> Its assigns an unique value for each row and when you sort be salary, it provides you the row number in an order you have sorted

**rank** -> Rank assigns the same value for each occurrences of the value. Eg: 6500 is twice and you same rank is assigned to both the rows, since its twice, 3rd rank will be skipper and 4th rank will be assigned to the next value

**dense_rank** --> Similar to rank, but will not skip the value of rank assigned to it.

Now coming to your question. Both aggregation and analytic function is applied to the column. You can check either rank or dense_rank result and compare it with the function you used, **sum(sal) over ( order by sal)**, you are summing the value in each phase of the rank and so, the values gets summed up in each level of ranking with respect to your previous values.

Comment: thank for the answer. So you mean to say there's dense_rank happening in the background?

Comment: Yes exactly. The right way to say is, it is the functionality when you use both aggregation and analytic functions together. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Because this

```
select ename, 
       sal, 
       sum(sal) over (order by sal) 
from emp
```

is shorthand for

```
select ename, 
       sal, 
       sum(sal) over (order by sal) RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
from emp
```

As per the SQL standard, and documentation here:

> If you omit the windowing_clause entirely, then the default is RANGE
>   BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174